# iOS Xcode 11 Launch Screen

Tags: ios, xcode

Can anyone please tell me why my project can't see the 'Launch Image Source'?

[image: Should be like this]

[image: Mine]

Thank you very very much!

Comment: Launch images are no longer supported. You must use a Launch screen storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“Use Asset Catalog” does not mean you are using the asset catalog *now;* it is a button that you *would* press if you *wanted* to use the asset catalog.

But you *don't* want to use the asset catalog. Instead, you want to choose a launch screen storyboard where it says Launch Screen File. Launch screen storyboards are now *required*. Apple knows that so they've taken away the button.